# Replicate result of Html.ActionLink in Javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, partial-views

I have the following code which displays a modal dialog in my MVC view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Insurance", "ViewInsurance", "Home", null, new { @class = "modal-link" })
```

When I click the link, it correctly brings up the PartialView from my Controller.  The controller code is here:

```
public ActionResult ViewInsurance()
{
    InsuranceViewModel vm = new InsuranceViewModel();
    vm.Name = "Medicare";
    return PartialView("_Insurance", vm);
}
```

However, I need to bring up the same dialog but through Javascript.  I need to dynamically change the input value (as Controller parameter) to display different data in the dialog.  I have omitted that from this example as it only complicates the issue.

I created a button to call the Javascript which I would like to do the same thing as the ActionLink does.  Here is that code:

```
<input type="button" name="style-a1" id="style-a1" value="View Insurance from Javascript" onclick="ViewInsuranceThroughJavascript()">
```

Here is the associated Javascript on the page:

```
<script>
    function ViewInsuranceThroughJavascript() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ViewInsurance", "Home")',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The result is that when using the ActionLink, the modal dialog displays just fine.  When using the javascript to all the controller, the controller action gets hit but the dialog does not get displayed.  I have hacked it to add an ID to the ActionLink and then have my Javascript call the onClick method of that object which will simulate the clicking of the ActionLink (works).  However, I do need to ultimately change an input parameter so that approach will not work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I've seen a post about jQuery not being able to display PartialViews.  There must be something I can do to simulate what is happening in the ActionLink click.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to add the html returned by the method to the DOM in the success callback - `success: function (data) { $(someElement).html(data); }`

Comment: This did help but the formatting is lost.  Do you know how to pass the htmlAttributes through the ajax post (similar to the ActionLink):
    new { @class = "modal-link" })

Comment: What do you mean _pass the class information through the post_? (that makes no sense). I'm guessing you mean add a class name to the button which is just `<input type="button" class="modal-link" ... >`

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Much appreciated.